# Checked event doesn't work correctly in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, knockout.js, checked

Below code works fine in all browsers except Firefox.

On first click on the checkbox it displays the correct value but in Firefox, it only shows correct value after check box is checked second time.

If I change `checked: checked` to `checked: checked()` then after the first click it shows the correct value in Firefox but then `enable:` doesn't work and it doesn't enable field.

```html
<input type="checkbox"
       data-bind="attr: { id: eId, title: description }, 
                  checked: checked,
                  enable: $root.enableInput, 
                  event: { change: function (newValue) { if (!newValue.checked()) { var TotalValue = !Helper.IsUndefinedOrNull($parent.totalValue()) ? Number($parent.totalValue().toString().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '')) : 0; chargeTypeName() == 'Percentage' ? testChargeAmount(chargeAmountValue() * totalValue) : testChargeAmount(chargeAmountValue()); } } }" />
<label data-bind="text: displayText, attr: { 'for': eId, title: description }"></label>
<input type="text" class="input_text currency"
       data-bind="value: testChargeAmount, precision: 2, attr: { title: description },
                  enable: checked(), css: { eAmountDisabled: !checked()} " />
<input type="text" class="input_text exceptionText"
       data-bind="value: exceptionText, 
                  enable: (checked() && $root.enableInput)" />
```

Comment: Please make sure to include minimal yet enough code to easily repro the issue. If possible create a code snippet or fiddle to demonstrate it.

Comment: In any case, you just about *never* want to hook up to the `change` event when using Knockout. You should let KO handle changing your view model values when events fire in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The `event` binding will cancel the default action of the event. If you don't want to cancel the default action, you must `return true` from the handler function:

```
event: {
    change: function() {
        ....
        return true;
    }
}
```

Reference: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-action